# RxJava zip that gets latest of other observable

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I want to achieve a `zip` that when one of the observable source emits data, it wont wait for other observable to emit there data but get the latest emitted data if there is one.

```
obs1 --true-|->
obs2 --true-|->  
obs3 --1-2-3-4->
```

the zip should execute the `TriFunction` with parameters

```
true, true, 1
true, true, 2
true, true, 3
true, true, 4
```

I hope my question make sense.

**Extended Question**

I already solve part of the problem, I got another problem for you guys.
`obs1` and `obs2` are expensive operations that will emit either `true` or `false`. What I needed is that in every emission of `obs3` I need to reexecute `obs1` or `obs2` if either of them emits `false` in the previous emission. What I wrote on the top is the best case where both `obs1` and `obs2` emits `true` on first emission of `obs3`.

```
-------1------------2-----------------3------------->
---true/false---true/re-execute---true/re-execute--->
---true/false---true/re-execute---true/re-execute--->
```

**Edit** The *"either"* is misleading on the extended question.

What I mean by that is if `obs1` is false on previous emission, reexecute `obs1`. If `obs2` is false on previous emission, reexecute `obs2`. Not reexecute them both if one of them is `false`.

Comment: So, you're saying you want to _combine_ the _latest_ values of each source? In that case, you are looking for `combineLatest` - yes, sometimes RxJava really _is_ that obvious. :-)

Comment: Here's the thing, I got 1 observable that needs the data from 2 observables in order t proceed(somewhat like a requirement). And that requirements are expensive, so its ideal to be executed only once. @david.mihola

Comment: Oh yeah combineLatest is the best fit. Thanks @david.mihola

Comment: By the way @david.mihola, what will happen if one of the source completes?

Comment: I am guessing that `combineLatest` will complete if any of the sources completes, but to be honest, I haven't yet relied on that behavior. So it's better to write a short test example.

Comment: @david.mihola
I run a simple code to verify. The combineLatest waits for the very last observable to finish before it completes.

https://gist.github.com/novodimaporo/06be7555fb579bd2a58392122f81a917

Comment: That's good to know! Thanks for the update!

Comment: Hi @david.mihola I updated my question. You might want to share your thoughts, write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** the extended question is a completely different problem that requires different operators, for example:

```
Observable<Boolean> obs1 = ...
Observable<Boolean> obs2 = ...

Observable<Integer> obs3 = ...

Function3<Integer, Boolean, Boolean> func = ...

// store last result of obs1 and obs2
boolean[] lastResults = { false, false };

// for each main value
obs3.concatMap(v -> {
    // if any of the previous results were false
    if (!lastResults[0] || !lastResults[1]) {
        // run both obs1 and obs2 again
        return Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, (a, b) -> {
            // save their latest results
            lastResult[0] = a;
            lastResult[1] = b;
            // apply the function to get the output
            return func(v, a, b);
        });
    }
    // otherwise call the function with true
    return Observable.just(func.apply(v, true, true));
})
.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Hi @akarnokd, updated my question to show my whole problem.

Comment: What I have in mind is to use `withLatestFrom` like what you said, then `scan()` on `obs1` and `obs2`. But `scan()` dont help a lot because I need to go inside the scan first before I can access the accumulated value and process my logic inside the `BiFunction` but my logic is written in rx, I cant use it inside the `BiFunction`.

Comment: Oh Sir @akarnokd, since you put that variable there my mindset about rx is broken. Is that really okay? access data outside the stream?

Comment: For one time consumed observables, yes. If you subscribe to this multiple times, you'll have to put the `lastResults` and the `obs3.concatMap(...)` part into `Observable.defer(() -> { ... })`.

Comment: `withLatestFrom` and `scan` don't produce the behavior you specified in the extended question.

Comment: wow, okay cool thanks @akarnokd. I got one last clarification. I got a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930560/rxjava2-publish). That is marked as answered but Im not satisfied with it.

Comment: That's a reasonable answer there. What's wrong with it in your opinion?

Comment: It did not answer my question really. What I have in mind but havent tested yet is that, the `Observable.merge` inside `publish` will only be created once, and without `publish` the `Observable.merge` will be created every time theres a data emitted from the upstream. Its like a one time observable.